# ndigitos[c - '0']++

Tags: c

No sabría que hace este if, espero que podáis ayudarme

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int c, i;
    int ndigitos[10];

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
           ndigitos[i] = 0; /*Inicialización del vector ndigitos*/

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
            if(c >= '0' && c <= '9') /*Digitos*/
            ndigitos[c - '0'] ++;`
    }
    printf("%d\n", ndigitos[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

No sé que quiere decir `ndigitos[c - '0']++`

Answer (score 0):

Bueno lo que pasa es que ndigitos es un arreglo de enteros deacuerdo?
Cuando ndigitos[c - '0'] ++; la parte de c - '0' calcula sus valores en ascii y los resta. es como decir c = '9', 9 en ascii es 57 - 48 que es 0 es ascii, serian 9 nove? entonces en el espacio 9 aumento mi contador. ese arreglo cuenta las veces que se repite cada digito.

Eso si revisa tu codigo esta mal ordenado y asi como esta no va a correr..

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisa [ask], Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

> > No sé que quiere decir ndigitos[c - '0']++

Básicamente tu programa lo que hace es almacenar en el arreglo, la cantidad de veces que se repita el dígito. Si el usuario ingresa `623244`, debería dar como resultado por pantalla:

```
Digito (2): 2 
Digito (3): 1
Digito (4): 2
Digito (6): 1
```

Vamos a explicar como funciona esta línea de código:

```
if(c >= '0' && c <= '9') 
    ndigitos[c - '0']++;
```

Seguiremos con el ejemplo de arriba, asumiremos que la variable `c` tiene guardado el código [ASCII](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/) (en este caso es el 54, equivale al caracter 6), para poder incrementar la variable en el arreglo, necesitaría hallar el índice. Entonces esta expresión: `c - '0'` sirve para eso, para encontrar el índice donde vamos hacer el incremento. Si `c` vale 54, entonces al momento de evaluar la expresión `c - '0'`, quedaría: `54 - 48` = `6`, como ves, en el índice 6 es donde se debe hacer el incremento.

Este código esta incompleto:

```
printf("%d\n", ndigitos[i]);
```

La forma correcta sería hacerlo con un bucle:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if(ndigitos[i] != 0)
      printf("Digito (%d): %d\n", i, ndigitos[i]);
}
```

Por cierto, esta condición:

```
(c = getchar()) != EOF
```

Generaría un bucle infinito. La forma correcta sería:

```
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
```

El bucle solo hará iteraciones hasta encontrar un salto de línea o el caracter `EOF`.